# IF statement ignoring keyboard input

Tags: python, if-statement, stdin

I have been trying to run a program using keyboard input to decide whether or not to run the program and the if statement is ignoring the input and always defaults to the else statement. Here is my code.

```
import random
import time
import sys

print("Do you want to run the program? Yes/No")
ans = sys.stdin.readline()

time.sleep(1)

if ans == "Yes" or ans == "yes":

    '''Body of IF statement'''

else:
    print("Alright, have a great day!")
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `input()` function?

Comment: Use `input()` as @Barmar recommends.  Does `says.stdin.readline()` collect the terminating new line as well, that could be trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readline()` includes the newline in its result. Use `strip()` to remove it (and any other surrounding whitespace).

```
ans = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

Or use the more normal `input()` function:

```
ans = input("Do you want to run the program? Yes/No")
```

And use `lower()` intead of `or` to allow case-insensitive response (unless you really want to treat `YES` and `yES` as no).

```
if ans.lower() == 'yes':
```